# zlib_1.2.9 not found required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16

Tags: python, zlib, libpng

After downloading zlib-1.2.9 on Ubuntu 18.04 I have these problems opening one of my softwares (Schrodinger suites).

```
ImportError: /opt/schrodinger2017-1/mmshare-v3.7/lib/Linux-x86_64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
```

Even though I have tried to install this library by these steps:

Downloading them (https://zlib.net/fossils/) and opening a terminal in the extracted directory and writing: `./configure` then `sudo make` and finally `sudo make install` and the process terminates without any errors, But this error doesn't fix for my software.

I could run my software in Ubuntu 16.04 correctly. also I have tried to install other libraries like `zlib1g`, `libpng` etc. but they didn't fix my issue. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score -3):

After I did some trial and error, I found something that makes it work mysteriously. On some other application, people said that running GUI application should be running on `gksudo`, which could be installed on

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

instead of `sudo`. I wonder if this would fix the problem of yours.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Doesn't look like this answers the question, as the OP never mentioned and error with `sudo` but a version mismatch with a system library.